# OpenNI RedistMaker - Build Fail on Mac OS

Tags: kinect, openni

I follow the OpenNI installation guide in README here https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI. I have installed libtool and libusb also. However, when I run `./RedistMaker` under Platform/Linux-x86/CreateRedist, I got such error message:

```
PrimeSense OpenNI Redist * 
2011-10-12 23:18:46 * ********************************* 
Taking version... version is 1.3.3.6 
Building OpenNI... In file included from ../../../../Source/OpenNI/ 
XnDump.cpp:25: ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:167: warning: ‘warning’ 
attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:168: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h: 
169: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../ 
Include/XnDump.h:170: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive 
ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:171: warning: ‘warning’ attribute 
directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:172: warning: ‘warning’ 
attribute directive ignored In file included from ../../../../Source/ 
OpenNI/XnDump.cpp:25: ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:167: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h: 
168: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../ 
Include/XnDump.h:169: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive 
ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:170: warning: ‘warning’ attribute 
directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:171: warning: ‘warning’ 
attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:172: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored In file included 
from ../../../../Include/XnDumpWriters.h:7, from ../../../../Source/ 
OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.h:7, from ../../../../Source/OpenNI/ 
XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:4: ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:167: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h: 
168: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../ 
Include/XnDump.h:169: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive 
ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:170: warning: ‘warning’ attribute 
directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:171: warning: ‘warning’ 
attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:172: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../Source/OpenNI/ 
XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual 
XnDumpWriterFileHandle XnDumpFileWriter::OpenFile(const XnChar, 
XnBool, const XnChar)’: ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: 
25: error: invalid conversion from ‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ to 
‘void’ ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In member 
function ‘virtual void XnDumpFileWriter::Write(XnDumpWriterFileHandle, 
const XnUInt8, XnUInt32)’: ../../../../Source/OpenNI/ 
XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘void’ to 
‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In 
member function ‘virtual void 
XnDumpFileWriter::CloseFile(XnDumpWriterFileHandle)’: ../../../../ 
Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:39: error: invalid conversion from 
‘void*’ to ‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ In file included from ../../../../Include/ 
XnDumpWriters.h:7, from ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.h: 
7, from ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:4: ../../../../ 
Include/XnDump.h:167: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive 
ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:168: warning: ‘warning’ attribute 
directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:169: warning: ‘warning’ 
attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h:170: warning: 
‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../Include/XnDump.h: 
171: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive ignored ../../../../ 
Include/XnDump.h:172: warning: ‘warning’ attribute directive 
ignored ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In member 
function ‘virtual XnDumpWriterFileHandle 
XnDumpFileWriter::OpenFile(const XnChar, XnBool, const 
XnChar)’: ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:25: error: 
invalid conversion from ‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ to ‘void*’ ../../../../Source/ 
OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void 
XnDumpFileWriter::Write(XnDumpWriterFileHandle, const XnUInt8, 
XnUInt32)’: ../../../../Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:33: error: 
invalid conversion from ‘void’ to ‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ ../../../../Source/ 
OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void 
XnDumpFileWriter::CloseFile(XnDumpWriterFileHandle)’: ../../../../ 
Source/OpenNI/XnDumpFileWriter.cpp:39: error: invalid conversion from 
‘void*’ to ‘XN_FILE_HANDLE’ lipo: can't figure out the architecture 
type of: /var/folders/8L/8LNYMSgEE5mYsWyaUxuEUE+++TI/-Tmp-// 
ccTxpyjf.out make[1]: ** [Release/XnDumpFileWriter.o] Error 1 make: 
*** [OpenNI] Error 2 failed to execute: make PLATFORM=x86 -C ../Build 
> /Users/wilson100/Projects/OpenNI/Platform/Linux-x86/CreateRedist/ 

Output/BuildOpenNI.txt Building Failed!
```

I am doing on my Mac OS/X 10.6 (snow leopard) and my xcode is 3.6.2. I have update my CMake and any library I can think of but still 
failed. My OpneNI version is 1.3.3.6 stable. Can someone tell me which 
step I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Well I can build it successfully if I go back to version 1.3.2.1 (but there will be a minor permission denied problem, which you can work around it by create a tmp file). So it's an alternative before openni community release update.

Update: This has been fixed in latest update.

Comment: Am getting the same errors in version Version 1.5.4.0 - May 7th 2012

Comment: I still have the same problem for Version 1.5.7.10. I have Xcode 7.3.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Are you guys using the right compiler version? Make sure you install Mono also, the opensource .Net implementation.